# Are there any ways to set specified default username and password in TiDB docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tidb

Based on TiDB official docker compose article, it sets default username/password to root/""
https://docs.pingcap.com/zh/tidb/v3.0/deploy-test-cluster-using-docker-compose

Does anyone know how to set default username/password in the following YAML?
ex: tidb/passwd

**docker-compose.yml** is in the following link:

https://github.com/pingcap/tidb-docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

It does not set any username or password, the `root/""` is just the default value of TiDB.

The YAML files in that repo do not support setting username and password.
You can set them manually after the creation.

BTW, the tidb-docker-compose repo was not maintained for a long time, suggest deploying the TiDB cluster with [kind](https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb-in-kubernetes/stable/get-started#create-a-kubernetes-cluster-using-kind), then you can initialize the
TiDB Cluster following the [doc](https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb-in-kubernetes/stable/initialize-a-cluster).